# Any ideas on how I can implement the .Bind extension that was available with Xamarin.Forms.Markup when using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit in XF 5 -pre 5

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here is the code that I have:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit;

namespace Templates
{
    public partial class LinkGrid : Grid
    {
        public LinkGrid()
        {
            var TL1 = new Label()
            {

            }.Bind(Label.TextProperty, nameof(Text1), source: this);
```

I was using "using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;" but now I am trying 5.0 - pre5 this is no longer available so I added Xamarin.CommunityToolkit and it would appear it's still not available. Does anyone know the history behind this. Has that functionality just been dropped?

[image]

Comment: `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` not `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit;` they don't come from the same package even that it looks like `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` is included in `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65170252/any-ideas-on-how-i-can-implement-the-bind-extension-that-was-available-with-xam#comment115214131_65170252) `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup;` and not `using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit;` they don't come from the same package even that it looks like it is the case.

in other words `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` is not included in `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit`.

- `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit` is the namespace that comes from [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit).
- `Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup` is the namespace that comes from [Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup).

Comment: Thanks, I was mistakenly under the impression that Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup would be included in Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.  Works good now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the correct namespace

```
using Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was mistakenly under the impression that Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.Markup would be included in Xamarin.CommunityToolkit.  Works good now.  Thanks